# Handling Parent WndProc From Child Component

Tags: delphi, winapi

Iam working on a new Component , and i want to handle all parent messages .

```
Type
 TMyComponent= class(TComponent)
//Bla bla
/..
//.
published
property Parent: TWinControl read FParent write SetParent;

end;
```

i want to get access to Parent WndProc (Handling all parent messages) . is there any way to handle Parent WndProc from my TMyComponent ?

Comment: The `SetParent` setter already exists and it's virtual. You can override it.

Comment: @TLama Not in `TComponent`

Comment: @David, well, so then `SetParentComponent`.

Comment: @TLama That's different altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FParent: TWinControl;
    FParentWindowProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
    procedure SetParent(Value: TWinControl);
  published
    property Parent: TWinControl read FParent write SetParent;
  end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetParent(Value: TWinControl);
begin
  if Value=FParent then
    exit;

  if Assigned(FParent) then
    FParent.WindowProc := FParentWindowProc;
  FParentWindowProc := nil;

  FParent := Value;

  if Assigned(FParent) then
  begin
    FParentWindowProc := FParent.WindowProc;
    FParent.WindowProc := WindowProc;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  // do whatever we want with the message
  FParentWindowProc(Message);// delegate to parent's window procedure
end;
```

Comment: The problems will begin if you have 2 or more components trying to handle Parent's WindowProc the above way.

Comment: @Serg That's a fundamental problem that is completely independent of this answer. Because window procedure dispatch is unicast.